# In Excel how can we find how many columns lie within the range and populate it in another column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's Say:

```
Column1   Column2   Column3  Column4  Upperbound  lowerbound   Result 
5           6         7        8         5.67        7.34        2
6           7         8        9         6            8          1
```

I have to find how many columns lie between upper bound and lower bound and populate in Result column.

Can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: what do you mean by lie ?

Comment: Dr. Xavier, presumably, given the example they gave, greater than the lower bound and less than the upper bound (although they've labelled the columns incorrectly).

Answer (score 1):

Are the number of values fixed at 4?

If so, use "countifs"

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:D1,">" & E1, A1:D1,"<" & F1)
```

Note that to use a cell-reference as a criteria, we essentially need to concatenate - i.e.

">" & E1 rather than ">E1"